# Upgrading to Windows 7 64 bit. Getting The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application Error

Tags: java, odbc, sqlexception

I have been developing a java application on a 32 bit Windows XP machine and it has been working fine.  The application connects to an Oracle DB2.  Recently our company has been upgrading to Windows 7 64 bit.  When attempting to run the application on the new 64 bit machine, it throws the following error:

"The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

I set up the DSN using Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe but this did not help.  The .jar file was created on the 32 bit Windows XP machine.

Here is the code snippet causing problems:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String database = "jdbc:odbc:DSN;UID="+userid+";PWD="+ password + ";MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=DSN;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
```

Is this possibly loading a 64 bit driver when the application is ran on Windows 7 and thus causing problems?  If so, how can I get it to load a 32 bit driver instead?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.